How to grep a word and also get the word before/after
How can I modify this command:
$ echo "Alex Long, Peter Bright and other names" | grep -io "alex"
Alex

so that the output is Alex Long -- i.e. also get the next word.
In another variation I need to grep the word Bright and get Peter Bright? i.e. also get previous word.
Obviously the exception would be the first word of the line (no previous) and the last one (no next word).

$ echo "Alex Long, Peter Bright and other names" | egrep -io "alex\s\S+"
results in Alex Long,
echo "Alex Long, Peter Bright and other names" | egrep -io "\S+\s+Bright" results in Peter Bright
Is that good enough?

With GNU grep: grep -ioP "(\w+ )?alex( \w+)?"?

Thanks Cyrus for this. Happy to accept this if you could write it as an answer.

There's a general case here about finding a word and an adjacent one (whatever the context, possibly from some command's output), but if you have a comma-separated list, it might be better to focus on the delimiters. (What if one of the names is Alex V. Long or so?)

That is a good point ikkachu. I just checked and the list (around a thousand names) and they all look simple non-hyphenated first and surname pairs (no middle names). But the separation is a mess -- there are commas, blanks, tabs and even semicolons!

The list belongs to my primary school from fifty years ago. Some I can remember by first name and others by family name. Hoping that I can grep what I remember and see if the full name rings a bell.

If you want to handle the Alex Alex Something cases:
$ echo "Alex Alex Long, Peter Bright and other names" |
   pcre2grep -o0 -o1 '\bAlex(?=(\s+\w+))'
Alex Alex
Alex Long

$ echo "Alex Alex Long, Peter Bright and other names" |
  perl -lne 'print $&.$1 while /\bAlex(?=(\s+\w+))/g'
Alex Alex
Alex Long

The idea being to capture the word after Alex inside a look-ahead operator so that after finding the first Alex word, we carry on searching after that Alex rather than after the word that follows it so we can find all occurrences of Alex.
You can take a similar approach to get the word before Bright:
$ echo "Alex Long, Peter Bright Bright and other names" |
   perl -lne 'print $&.$1 while /\b\w+(?=(\s+Bright\b))/g'
Peter Bright
Bright Bright

Above words mean sequences of word characters, that is alnums and underscore; ASCII only unless you add the -C option (-u for pcre2grep) or -Mopen=local to decode the input as per the locale's encoding:
$ echo 'Stéphane Chazelas' |
   perl -lne 'print $&.$1 while /\b\w+(?=(\s+Chazelas\b))/g'
phane Chazelas

$ echo 'Stéphane Chazelas' |
   perl -C -lne 'print $&.$1 while /\b\w+(?=(\s+Chazelas\b))/g'
Stéphane Chazelas


It is not trivial to know exactly what would constitute names and what will constitute "separators" ( commas, ␣and␣, etc)
Based on your own example I could propose this solution, that put each "full name" on its own lines by transforming any ␣and␣, and any other non-alphanumerical (and non-space, not tab) characters, into a newline "\n" :
fullname () {
  for part_of_name in "$@"; do
    cat file_with_all_names |
      sed -e 's/ and /,/g'  |
      LC_ALL=C tr -c ' \t[:alnum:]' '\n' |
      grep -i "$part_of_name"
  done
}
# and then:
fullname "alex" "bright"

If you want it as a filter, as shown in your question, it is simple:
filter_fullname () {
  regex_filter=$( echo "$*" | tr " " "|" )
     #this just assume that each things searched do not contain a space... ymmv
  sed -e 's/ and /,/g'  |
    LC_ALL=C tr -c ' \t[:alnum:]' '\n' |
    grep -i -E "$regex_filter"
}
# and then
some_input | filter_fullname "something"
some_input | filter_fullname "alex" "bright"
   # will show all full names from some_input matching either "alex" or "bright"


Making assumptions (for simplicity) that names are: always represented with proper casing, single character names are not "a thing", and that they don't contain anything other than letters (IE no punctuation characters).
grep -Eo "Alex [A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z][a-z]+ Bright([, ]|$)"

Names are hard.  If you have more complex requirements, it's going to get much more complicated very quickly.
I'd imagine all of my assumptions are violations of this.

If I were you I'd reformat your list as a CSV of first and last names which you can then use Unix tools on or read into MS Excel and do whatever you like with there, e.g. using any POSIX awk:
$ echo "Alex Long, Peter Bright Joe Schmo; Anne O'Hara" |
    awk -F "[^[:alpha:]']+" -v OFS=',' '
        BEGIN { print "First", "Last" }
        { for (i=1;i<=NF; i+=2) print $i, $(i+1) }
'
First,Last
Alex,Long
Peter,Bright
Joe,Schmo
Anne,O'Hara

